# Inconsistent error message

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I use the django-registration module, but this is a django/python question.

In a custom view:

```
def register(self, request, **cleaned_data):

    firstname, lastname, email, password = cleaned_data['firstname'], cleaned_data['lastname'], cleaned_data['email'], cleaned_data['password']
    if Site._meta.installed:
        site = Site.objects.get_current()
    else:
        site = RequestSite(request)
    new_user = RegistrationProfile.objects.create_inactive_user(email, email,
                                                                password, firstname,
                                                                lastname, site)

    signals.user_registered.send(sender=self.__class__,
                                 user=new_user,
                                 request=request)
    return new_user
```

And when I send my form, I get this error:

```
TypeError at /accounts/register/
 create_inactive_user() takes at most 6 arguments (7 given)
```

pointing at my create_inactive_user(email, email, password, firstname, lastname, site) ... that have 6 arguments!!!

I tried with hard-coded values, but I get the same message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by [the code](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/8f242e35ef7c004e035e54b4bb093c32bf77c29f/registration/models.py?at=default#cl-73), that create method isn't expecting a first name and last name argument - self will get passed implicitly, but it wants you to pass it 5 variables - username, email, password, site, and an optional send_email.

You're giving it too many (and incorrect) arguments :)

Comment: All right, I was totally off the track. In fact I defined a custom create_inactive_user() method but I was not calling it properly!

Comment: Glad you got it sussed!

Answer (score 0):

When you call a method, `self` is implicitly added as the first argument.

Did you forget to include `self` as the first argument in the function definition?

Comment: It is true only for class methods.

Comment: if it's not in a class, it's not a method.